# Sort NSMutableArray Of multiple Objects without keys

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray of objects, below is the struct:

```
//object at index i
locations {
   NSString* address;
   NSString* state;
   NSNumber* distance;
}
```

I have **10000** object like the above structure in the NSMutableArray.
How do order this array so that the locations are in order by the NSNumber distance?

I tried this:

```
lowToHigh = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[locationArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowToHigh]];
```

is using the `sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance"` wrong? since distance isn't actually a key, it NSNumber* distance.

edit in my header `@property (strong, nonatomic)NSNumber* _distance;` and then `@synthesize _distance = distance;` in my methods file but this is in locationObjects.* object class. Then I import this in my current class I am doing this sorting. Is that an issue? 
How I import is `locationObjects* locObj = [[locationObjects alloc] init];`

Comment: If you have a property `-(NSString*)distance` in addition to ivar `distance`, your trick should just work.

Comment: @HotLicks it makes the array only have one object 10000 times. and dasblinkenlight its a NSNumber

Comment: Did you alloc/init the actual lowToHigh NSSortDescriptor? (The 'Specifying Sorts Using NSSortDescriptor' section on this doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: yes of course, @tarheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *lowToHigh = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *mySortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lowToHigh];
NSArray *sortedArray = [locationArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:mySortDescriptors];
```

Comment: The only difference between what I tried and what you posted is the `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` vs `sortUsingDescriptors`. Which unfortunately gives me the same exact sorting as I did before posting this question.

Comment: Sorry I was primarily referring to alloc/initing them, but I now see the comment asking about it. Besides that they are the exact same.

Comment: I think my issue is I don't have a key called distance only an NSNumber called distance.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato -- You mean you never defined the `@property` called distance, I suspect.

Comment: nope I do, in my header `@property (strong, nonatomic)NSNumber* _distance;`
and then `@synthesize _distance = distance;` in my methods file

Comment: Look at this, I think he is trying to do almost the exact same thing except with an NSDate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: and @joel you posted practically the same answer as him. and it doesn't work in this case. I tried following that before i posted this question actually, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that too (to my understanding it is the standard way of doing this). I just have never tried his other implementations and figured I would just send you there. I am sorry they did not work.

Comment: I have a feeling, I must be doing something wrong thats completely way from what my original question has asked. +1 and accepted this as the answer for all the hard work.

Comment: Thanks John and if I figure something out I will be sure to let you know!

Comment: @Joel guess what my data inside the array was all the same. I found out I wasn't releasing my data after it was put into the array, and for what ever reason, when I added new data into the array, it was really pushing the retained data from the first time the values were set. So I was correct with my sorting, and so were you. thanks

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Oh wow! Thank you for letting me know, I will make sure I keep that in the back of my mind! I am glad it is working!